# Pig Script useHCatalog flag?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have written simple pig script to read data from hive table.

```
A = LOAD 'default.movie' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
DUMP A;
```

It is working when i run through hue pig user interface. But it uses a flag `useHCatalog`.

[image]

When i run this using command line using same flag it is working

```
pig -useHCatalog sample.pig
```

But how can i run without this flag by providing required jar files and configuration in the pig script. I tried this. But doesn't work

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/hive/lib/*.jar
REGISTER /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/*.jar
REGISTER /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers/hbase/lib/*.jar
```

It throws an error when i run without flag

> 2015-12-15 05:05:55,379 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer -
>   exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Table not found :
>   default.movie table not found Failed to parse: Can not retrieve schema
>   from loader org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader@25bdba7a
>           at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:198)
>           at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1678)
>           at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1411)
>           at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:344)
>           at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:369)
>           at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:355)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:769)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)

I just want to know, what is behind `useHCatalog` flag. what i have to register in order to work fine?

Comment: Last time I used pig with hive, I didn't even use the flag and it worked without registering anything manually...

Comment: Anyways, your error says "table not found" it looks like HCatLoader loaded correctly because otherwise you'd get a different error saying it couldn't be found on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the hive configuration as well, namely the file `hive-site.xml` which will point pig to the metastore. Otherwise pig does not know where to look for the table information.

This page might be helpful: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore

Comment: Hi do you know how to point that file to pig. I can't able to figure it out from that document?

Comment: it should be something like this: export PIG_OPTS=-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://<hostname>:<port> and then start up pig